# Row base calculation wrt the radio buttons in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I was a Tableau user and I started to use PowerBI recently. However, I have some troubles about the way to make some inner calculations.

Say I have got a toy data with 5 columns as below,

| Data | Type1 | Type2 | Currency1 | Currency2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 1.1 | 0.7 |
| 10 | 9 | -5 | 1.3 | 0.74 |
| 8 | 12 | 22 | 1.6 | 0.8 |

What I want to achieve is that creating a new column (it was called calculation field in Tableau), by using some radio buttons (called parameter field in Tableu) as follows,

**Radio Button 1 :** Includes *Type1* and *Type2*

**Radio Button 2 :** Includes *Currency1* and *Currency2*

My new calculation has to be done wrt the selections of those calculations.
Say, if `Type2` and `Currency1` selected,  I want to get product of the data column with  the selected ones as a new column like,

| Data | Type1 | Type2 | Currency1 | Currency2 | NewColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 1.1 | 0.7 | 16.5 |
| 10 | 9 | -5 | 1.3 | 0.74 | -65 |
| 8 | 12 | 22 | 1.6 | 0.8 | 281.6 |

Of course It should be dynamic with the combinations of the selected ones.

*What Have I tried ?*

I created the buttons and achieved the single by the guide of [this](https://powerbi.tips/2019/08/dynamic-visuals-using-buttons/) link.

```
Currency = 
SWITCH(
  SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[Id])
   ,1,Data[Currency1]
   ,2,Data[Currency2]
)

Type= 
SWITCH(
  SELECTEDVALUE(Table2[Id])
   ,1,Data[Type1]
   ,2,Data[Type2]
```

But It did not work of course. Since It needs `SUM` etc in the calculation.

My final goal is to use that dynamically created new column in my graphs, tables etc.

I also thought wide-long format transformation but I am not so sure!

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use calculated columns to achieve this because data shown in columns is static.

You need to create a measure, so in order to do that:

I first created 2 tables as you did that only contains id columns and I used to create 2 slicers.
Then i used the following measure:

```
Measure = 
VAR __selectedType = SELECTEDVALUE( Table1[ID] )
VAR __selectedCurrency = SELECTEDVALUE( Table2[ID] )

VAR __type =
SWITCH(
    __selectedType,
    1, SUM( 'Table'[Type1] ),
    2, SUM( 'Table'[Type2] ),
    0
)

VAR __currency =
SWITCH(
    __selectedCurrency,
    1, SUM( 'Table'[Currency1] ),
    2, SUM( 'Table'[Currency2] ),
    0
)

Return __type * __currency * SUM( 'Table'[Data] )
```

Then drag the measure in a table visual. This is the expected result.
[image]